# How to Read Data from .rda with read.table

Tags: r

I have a file flights.rda and i can't read it with read.table. Pls help me. This is the link for it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rhSLipqpHJjafSdCVizninz6v0wJBfMN/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you tried `load("flights.rda")`?

Comment: I tried it but when i use 
x <- read.table("flights.rda", header= TRUE, sep=",", skipNul = TRUE)
then i have x with 11434 obs. of 1 variable but flights.rda has 162049 obs. of 16 variables

Comment: All you have to do is `load("flights.rda")` and that will import the flights tibble to your workspace. There's no need for `read.table`.